# Copy/Past from vim command-line mode

Tags: vim

Is there a way to read (yank) or/and write (paste) to the buffer form the vim's command-line mode ?
I mean beside the `norm`  command ?

for example:

1. how can I put the content of register 'a' into line 5, position 6 from the command-line, without using the `normal` command?
2. how to store the letters in register 'b' from the current buffer from position (line 3, col 4) till 5, 2 ?

Comment: What you describe is pretty much the purpose of `:normal`. Why not use it?

Comment: I think you're looking for commands like [`:delete`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:delete), [`:yank`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:yank), [`:put`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:put).

Comment: @phd, no, because all those are line-wise, which is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I put the content of register 'a' into line 5, position 6 from the command-line, without using the `normal` command?

The built-in editing-related Ex commands are all line-wise by design so they can't be used for charater-wise edits. They simply don't know anything beyond line numbers. That is the job of normal mode and executing normal mode commands in the command-line is done via `:normal`.

This would be one way to do what you want with `:normal`:

```
:5normal 5l"ap
```

And this would be a substitution-based alternative:

```
:5s/\%>6c/\=getreg("a")/
```

And this would be a vimscript-based alternative:

```
:call getline('5')->substitute('\%>6c', getreg('a'), '')->setline('5')
```

Pick your poison.

> how to store the letters in register 'b' from the current buffer from position (line 3, col 4) till 5, 2 ?

There is no way to do that with the built-in editing-related Ex commands, for the reason mentioned above.

Just use `:normal`, that is what it was made for.